# What does this icon in iOS Stardew Valley mean?

Tags: ios, stardew-valley

[image]

Wondering if anyone knows what this icon means in top left hand side of screen. I can press it but don’t know what it actually does. This is on IOS version.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in [the wiki](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Mobile_Controls), it's a toggle button for the controls:

> - When the toggle button is on, the control method is set to whatever method has been selected from the drop down.
> - When the toggle button is off, the controls switch to Tap-to-move & Auto-Attack.